# What are Retro levels?

Tags: runner2

I was running along in 1-4 when I missed a jump, and suddenly things went all funky. Well, funkier:

[image]

How did I trigger this new, retro-themed level?

How are they different from regular levels? And why did I get a counter saying 1/25 Congratulations when I beat it?

Comment: Possible dupe of this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/106915/where-can-i-find-all-the-retro-challenges

Comment: @Retrosaur Not a dupe. But surprised the questions got asked in the order they did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Retro levels are "secret" levels that can only be found by finding a yellow "game cartridge" in certain levels, as seen below (the picture corresponds to 1-4, which is Windy Interlude).

[image: Now with 420% more freehand!]

These are essentially "bonus" levels.  They do not affect what score you get in the level you can find the portals.

Once you find a "Retro" level in a certain level, you can always revisit it on the main map screen by pressing "K".

There are also 25 of them out there. Collect 'em all!

Comment: I am so glad you mentioned I can revisit them as that passed me by until just then...! Does the minimap highlight that there is a retro level in it, or do I just have to go into each level and find it?

Comment: @franglais Fortunately, yes.  There will be a silhouette of a box on the minimap to indicate which levels will have retro levels.

Comment: @franglais As far as I know that little cartridge only appears once you've already unlocked the retro level.